# App crashes when creating Universal app with multiple XIB and single View Controller

Tags: xcode4.3, ios-universal-app

I created a Universal window app in Xcode 4.3.3. Later I added one View Controller(UniversalRootViewController) class without XIB. Then I created two XIB files(RootViewController_iPhone, RootViewController_iPad) and then connect these iPhone XIB file RootViewController_iPhone to the UniversalRootViewController class: RootViewController_iPhone -> Select File's Owner and changed the class name in Identity Inspector as UniversalRootViewController and then connect the view as outlet to UniversalViewController and did the same thing for RootViewController_iPad.

In App Delegate , I added the following lines of code.

```
UniversalRootViewController *controller = nil;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    controller = [[UniversalRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
}
else
{
    controller = [[UniversalRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self.window addSubview:controller];
}
```

Also I added these two key-value pairs in UniversalApp-Info.plist 
Main nib file base name : RootViewController_iPhone
Main nib file base name (iPad) : RootViewController_iPad

When I run this application, the app creates by displaying the following error message.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

I connected XIB files properly to View Controller. I don't know why the app crashes. Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the view outlet in the File's Owner to each view in the XIB file:
- Go to one of the XIB file (iphone for example) and drag with the left mouse button from the file owner to the top view below in objects. Select view.
- Do the same for the other XIB file

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening in your case but usually you see this message if you missed the outlet connection or if you have a connection set up in your nibs to a property that is missing on the target object. In this case a property named view.

Comment: I made all connections between ViewController and XIB. But the app is not working.

Comment: Have you checked if there is an outlet in the XIB that is connected to a property in header that does not exist anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing the two key-value pairs of Nib files in Universal-Info.plist. Now the app works perfectly without any crash.[image: I removed the following two lines]